# Defining a function in parts

Tags: functions

How can I define a piecewise function in Mathematica?

> I'm trying to define $$f_{A}(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned} 1, \quad x \in A\\ 0, \quad x\notin A \end{aligned}\right.$$
> where $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Have you looked at [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["`*"];
f[A_][x_] := Boole@MemberQ[A, x];
A = {x, y, z};
f[A][x]
```